# Communicate between subnets on different network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a Linux box that I have setup with 3 network interfaces, connected to 3 different networks, each with their own subnet. At a high level I am trying to achieve communications between devices on each of these networks to devices on each of the other networks.

The 3 network interfaces are configured as described:

**eth0 "WAN Port"**

eth0 is a fairly standard interface configured as a DHCP client and connected to an upstream network which has a DHCP server and provides a gateway to the internet.

IP: 192.168.100.105/24 (address assigned by DHCP server on network)

**eth1 "LAN Port"**

eth1 has been configured as a DHCP Server and acts as the gateway for a small LAN. The interface has been configured with the following command:

```
nmcli c add con-name eth1-dhcp-server type ethernet ifname eth1 ipv4.method shared ipv6.method ignore ipv4.addresses 10.79.0.1
```

IP: 10.79.0.1/24

**wlan0 "WiFi AP"**

wlan0 is configured similarly to eth1, providing a small LAN, but instead using a WiFi Access Point. The Access Point, DHCP server and static IP, is setup with the following commands:

```
nmcli d wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid <ss_id> password <password>
nmcli c modify Hotspot connection.autoconnect yes ipv4.addresses 10.80.0.1
```

IP: 10.80.0.1/24

**Ping Test Setup**

To test communication across networks I've connected the following devices to each of the networks.

| Device | Network (Identified by Linux box's network interface) | IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | eth0 | 192.168.100.145 |
| PC2 | eth1 | 10.79.0.77 |
| PC3 | wlan0 | 10.80.0.16 |

**Ping Test Results**

PC1 (192.168.100.145):

`ping 10.79.0.77` ✕ Fail

`ping 10.80.0.16` ✓ Success

PC2 (10.79.0.77):

`ping 192.168.100.145` ✓ Success

`ping 10.80.0.16` ✓ Success

PC3 (10.80.0.16):

`ping 192.168.100.145` ✓ Success

`ping 10.79.0.77` ✕ Fail

The results of this tests indicate some positive results, with successful routing of packets with destinations of 192.168.100.0/24 and 10.80.0.0/24, but not to 10.79.0.0/24.

**Troubleshooting Attempts**

After battling to try and get all packets routed successfully I've still made very little progress. However I have come across one interesting find to do with modifying the route metric of the 10.80.0.0/24 route, changing it from 150 to 101 (lower than the 10.79.0.0/24 route). This changes the ping behaviour so that packets with destination 10.79.0.0/24 get successfully routed, and now 10.80.0.0/24 are not. Setting them to the same metric did not get them to both work, so I'm not sure there is a related permanent fix here...

Original routing table:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.79.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.79.0.1 metric 101 
10.80.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.80.0.1 metric 150
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.105 metric 100
```

Modified routing table:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.79.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.79.0.1 metric 101 
10.80.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.80.0.1 metric 100 ** reduced from 150
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.105 metric 100
```

Is there anyone out there with a solid understanding on what is going on here? And even better yet a solution!

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It's unclear why this changes the behavior, as routes aren't sorted by metric in the first place. Routes are chosen based on whether they match the destination (and two different /24 routes cannot _possibly_ match the same destination), then based on prefix length (longest prefix having higher priority), and only then -- i.e. if you somehow had two "10.80.0.0/24" routes -- would the metric become relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised to find this as well. Any thoughts on other changes to try?

Comment: Check whether `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.{all,eth0,eth1,wlan0}.rp_filter` is set to 0, not 1 or 2. Use `ip route get <addr>` to query which route is used for what destination, in case there's something else (like policies in `ip rule`) that alters the behavior.

Comment: I checked my rp_filters and I had a mix of interfaces set to 1s and 2s:

`$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.{all,eth0,eth1,wlan0}.rp_filter`
`net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1`
`net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 2`
`net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 1`
`net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.rp_filter = 1`

Unfortunately after setting them all to 0, I still was seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: The `ip route get <addr>` also returned as expected for sample addresses on each subnet: `ip route get 10.79.0.77`
`10.79.0.77 dev eth1 src 10.79.0.1 uid 1000` and `ip route get 10.80.0.16`
`10.80.0.16 dev wlan0 src 10.80.0.1 uid 1000`

Comment: While pinging from "PC3" (10.80.0.16) my failed ping is returning: `ping 10.79.0.77`
`From 10.80.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable` it seems the 10.80.0.1 gateway (wlan0) is denying this packet before even trying to route the packet?

Comment: You still should ensure rp_filter is at 0 both globally and for each interface. (2 may also work, but 1 is definitely going to be problematic). "Destination Port Unreachable" does sound like a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally figured out the issue, and it had to do with iptable rules. I should have known.

I noticed in my iptable that there was `REJECT` policies with `reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`. This matched up with the `Destination Port Unreachable` response I was receiving from my failed pings.

You can see the original iptables output here:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.79.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.79.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.80.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.80.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have changed the order such that the `REJECT all-- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` rules were below all of the `10.79.0.0/24` and `10.80.0.0/24` rules.

Once I had changed the iptables accordingly everything seems to be working now! Updated iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.79.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.79.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.80.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.80.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I want to also thank @user1686 for their input and providing some helpful suggestions along the way!